# Can I create authentication without middleware?

Tags: laravel-5, basic-authentication, laravel-middleware

I'm newbie at Laravel development. I'm really confuse between middleware and authentication . Can I create authentication system without using middleware in Laravel 5.2 ?

Comment: a bit strange question. What do you mean? (check this section in the meanwhile on the best practices http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes of course.. you can think on middleware as code that run before your controller code but at the end if I simplify it its all just normal php code, you can always do whatever you do in middleware inside the controller function.

so instead of using middleware to protect route for authenticated users only, you can put the auth checking code in the controller